# Laravel contact form with confirm page

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm looking for sample code of Laravel contact form with confirm view

I asked this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53853687/adding-live-search-script-into-laravel-form
I'm thinking restart to make contact page that not using `{!! Form::`  way
that can combine ajax live search section.
I've been searching sample code that contact form with confirm view but I couldn't find it. Doesn't call "confirm view" ?
Could someone teach me how to call it please?

```
<div class="form-group{{ $errors->has('search') ? ' has-error' : '' }}">
                {!! Form::label('search', 'search:', ['class' => 'col-sm-2 control-label']) !!}

                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    {!! Form::text('search', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}

                    @if ($errors->has('search'))
                        <span class="help-block">
                            <strong>{{ $errors->first('search') }}</strong>
                        </span>
                    @endif
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Hi Blue, Do you want to show a confirmation message in the same page?

Comment: Hi. ＠Emmanuel Hdz Díaz Thank you for comment . No. 1st page is just input page. type name, email and procut name. Then 2nd page is only confirmation page. Message is like "Are you sure to send these info ?" if you okay. click send buttom. So then finaly 3rd page. it say .Your message has been sent Thank you for contact.

Comment: Ok, you need to use Ajax, in your input form don't set method and action, create a button and onClick function put the name of the Jquery script (here you can validate the fields and show the confirmation alert). Try to do it, post your results and we can continue with the next step.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ***Then 2nd page is only confirmation page.***

I don't see the reason for splitting this up over 3 pages.

If you are just looking to add a confirmation step in there, have you thought about using [onclick](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onclick.asp) to prompt the user to confirm? Saves you from jumping around pages and accomplishes what I *think* you're getting after here.

If the user input passes validation, your controller processes the data and sends you to the thank you page. If it doesn't, it directs the user back to the form page and tells them what the error was.

**Routes file:**

```
Route::post('/your/route', 'YourController@store');
```

**input-form.blade.php:**

```
<form method="POST" action="/your/route">
    @csrf 
    <!-- add your form inputs --> 
    <input type="text" name="fname" class="form-control" />
    <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" />

    <button class="btn" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure your credentials are correct?')">
</form>

@if ($errors->any())
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        <ul>
            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
            @endforeach
        </ul>
    </div>
@endif
```

**YourController:**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    // You'd want to expand on this a bit

    $validatedData = $request->validate([
        'fname' => required,
        'email' => required
    ]);

    // Process your data ... 


    // Then, return to your confirmation page 
    return view('thankyou-page');

}
```

**thankyou-page.blade.php**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="col-md-10">
        Thank you, your order is confirmed!
    </div>
    <!-- col --> 
</div>
<!-- container -->
```

You can [scroll through Laravels amazing documentation here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#creating-form-requests) that speaks to form validation more.

Comment: Dear @UkraineInTheMembrane Thank you so much. I love your explaing. Sorry for late to say Thank you. you help me alot!

Comment: No worries at all! Glad I could help out @blueink :)